# why can't upload deb package in my wordpress?

Tags: uploads

```
sudo vim   /var/www/html/wp/wp-config.php
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

I have add the line in wp-config.php.
[image]

why still can't upload deb package whose size is only 5m in my wordpress?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message speak for itself. The "file type is not allowed". WordPress upload only allowed for certain file types, see [Uploading Files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files).

Comment: You can customize  the file type which can be uploaded to whichever you like.

Comment: $existing_mimes['exe'] = 'application/exe'; it can make exe file to be uplaoded.

Answer (score -1):

sudo vim  /var/www/html/wp/wp-includes/functions.php

```
add_filter('upload_mimes','custom_upload_mimes');
function custom_upload_mimes ( $existing_mimes=array() ) {
    $existing_mimes['deb'] = 'application/deb';
    return $existing_mimes;
}
```

Comment: That's not the `functions.php` you want to touch. It will be overwritten with the next WP update.